# How To Get A Value From An Array Having Provided The Key?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to get the seniority value from this array

```
var jobs= [
  {
    "startDate": "5/2017",
    "endDate": null,
    "isCurrent": true,
    "seniority": "Senior",
  },
  {
    "startDate": "5/2013",
    "endDate": "5/2019",
    "isCurrent": false,
    "seniority": "Junior",
  },
]
```

and using this function to get the field and log it

```
function ArrayField(array,field){
  for (var index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
    if (array[index]===field) {
      return index;      
    }
    return false;
  }
}

console.log(ArrayField(jobs,"seniority"))
```

But it's only logging out false...
Where could I be going wrong ???

**Expected Output**

2 Separate Logs

```
"Senior"
"Junior"
```

I have tried

```
var jobs= [
  {
    "startDate": "5/2017",
    "endDate": null,
    "isCurrent": true,
    "seniority": "Senior",
  },
  {
    "startDate": "5/2013",
    "endDate": "5/2019",
    "isCurrent": false,
    "seniority": "Junior",
  },
]

function arrayField(array, field) {
  for (var index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
    if (field in array[index]) {
      return array[index][field]
    }
    return false;
  }
}

console.log(arrayField(jobs,"seniority"))
```

But it's only logging out one value

`"senior"`

Comment: why do you compare a value?

Comment: What is the expected value? Is it `["Senior","Junior"]`?

Comment: Youre comparing a whole object with a string..

Comment: `index` is something like `0`, `1`; `array[index]` is something like `{"startDate": ..., ...}`…!

Comment: It should be `array[index][field]=== field`

Comment: @callback It shouldn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is not possible.

Either get the ouput insode of the function or return an array and make the output outside of the function.

---

**Inside**

You could check if the property exist and make an output.

```js
function arrayField(array, field) {
  for (var index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
    if (field in array[index]) {
      console.log(array[index][field]);
    }
  }
}

var jobs = [{ startDate: "5/2017", endDate: null, isCurrent: true, seniority: "Senior" }, { startDate: "5/2013", endDate: "5/2019", isCurrent: false, seniority: "Junior" }];

arrayField(jobs, "seniority");
```

**Outside**

```js
function arrayField(array, field) {
  var result = [];
  for (var index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
    if (field in array[index]) {
      result.push(array[index][field]);
    }
  }
  return result;
}

var jobs = [{ startDate: "5/2017", endDate: null, isCurrent: true, seniority: "Senior" }, { startDate: "5/2013", endDate: "5/2019", isCurrent: false, seniority: "Junior" }];

arrayField(jobs, "seniority").forEach(v => console.log(v));
```

For getting more than one property, you could add more keys and use [rest parameters `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) to colect all keys in an array.

For mapping the wanted keys, you could join all wanted property values.

```js
function getValues(array, ...keys) {
    return array.map(object => keys.map(key => object[key]).join(', '));
}

var jobs = [{ startDate: "5/2017", endDate: null, isCurrent: true, seniority: "Senior" }, { startDate: "5/2013", endDate: "5/2019", isCurrent: false, seniority: "Junior" }];

console.log(getValues(jobs, 'seniority', 'startDate'));
```

Comment: This answers my question... However I want to have a `return` from the `For` Loop and Have the `Console.Log` At the bottom

Comment: what do you want to return? an array of values?

Comment: Just the individual values... Which your code is doing,,, But i don't want the log in the function... I want a return instead

Comment: Is it possible to add more fields i.e. `arrayField(jobs, "seniority",startDate)` to get a string with both by adding more parameters to the function as follows `function arrayField(array, field,secondField)..... ` To Get A String Like `"Senior, 5/2017"`

Comment: it is possible to add more keys and get a joind string back. please see edit.

Comment: Yeah... It works...Thanks...One last problem How can a line break be added between ``5/2017"`` and ``"Junior,``

Comment: where? in the console? then take the outside approach for the result.

Comment: yeah, A new line using the outside approach

Comment: How can I add a line break after a value has been generated ?

Answer (score 1):

You can get an array of values of the given key using `map()`

```js
var jobs = [{ startDate: "5/2017", endDate: null, isCurrent: true, seniority: "Senior" }, { startDate: "5/2013", endDate: "5/2019", isCurrent: false, seniority: "Junior" }];

const getField = (arr, feild) => arr.map(x => x[feild]);
console.log(getField(jobs,"seniority").join())
```

Comment: It is returning an array... I want strings in this case

Comment: @Dennis Can you please update the question and add expected output.

Comment: @Dennis You can use `join()` on array to convert it to string. See the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` to get value from the given object as follow

```js
var jobs= [
  {
    "startDate": "5/2017",
    "endDate": null,
    "isCurrent": true,
    "seniority": "Senior",
  },
  {
    "startDate": "5/2013",
    "endDate": "5/2019",
    "isCurrent": false,
    "seniority": "Junior",
  },
]

function ArrayField(array,field){
  return array.map((data, i) => data[field])
}
//Iterate all values and console
ArrayField(jobs,"seniority").forEach(value => console.log(value))
```

Comment: It is returning an array... I want strings in this case